# What is the best way to get config variables into a class in php 5?

Tags: php, oop

This is for my DB class. I am new to OO, been a procedural lad for some time, so I'm still a bit murky.

My first idea was using a bunch of setter functions/methods.. but after writing a whole bunch, I thought about using PHP's define function, like so.

```
define('MYSQL_USERNAME', 'jimbo');
```

Is this an accepted practice? What is the best practice? Should I really clutter my class with a bunch of setter functions (I am currently the only developer using these classes). What are your solutions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `const` only for creating mnemonic names for immutable constants in the class.  The `define()` function does not create constants as part of the class, it creates constants in the global space.

```
class MyClass
{
  const CONFIG_FILE = 'myapp.ini';
```

Class configuration data I usually declare as a `protected` hash-array in the class.  Keys are useful for mnemonics.  Values are defaults.

```
  protected $config = array(
    'logfile' => 'err.out',
    'debug' => false
  );
```

Then I load an "ini" format file with `parse_ini_file()` and use `array_merge()` to map the keys into your class config array:

```
  public function __construct() {
    $ini_data = parse_ini_file(self::CONFIG_FILE, __CLASS__);
    $this->config = array_merge($this->config, $ini_data);
  }

}
```

Comment: What's the overhead like on parsing an ini file? Do you think it would become an issue? I'd imagine a keyed array within PHP would be much quicker?

Comment: How do you go about securing this INI file? Place it above the root web accessible directory?

Comment: Parsing a PHP file versus reading an ini file are not significantly different.

Comment: Yes, secure an ini file as you would secure any of your other class-declaring code by placing it outside the docroot.  Only the actual PHP template files need to be accessible.

Comment: this sounds like the best solution (cos I know the ini will make more sense to a designer then a keyed array) so I'm going to place it above my docroot and name it something.ini.php Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's another advantage of ini files -- they're easy to edit.

Comment: The way this site is already set up (3 mini sites off a TLD) means that the ini might get lost in the folders above the root.. any other way of obscuring them? Blocking with .htaccess?

Comment: Well, I'd keep all my PHP classes outside the docroot (e.g. /var/www/library as a sister of /var/www/htdocs) and add that location to PHP's include path.  Unfortunately, parse_ini_file() doesn't heed the PHP include path, so you need to use an absolute path.

Comment: I found that if I begin the ini file with <? and end with ?> PHP will still parse it but won't output the contents if called directly. Seems like a solution to me!

Comment: That's a bad solution, since the PHP module could fail leading to your file being read as text. Best to follow Bill's suggestion and keep out of the docroot

Comment: But if the PHP module does fail, then won't all of my code be readable?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason you shouldn't keep your code under the docroot.

Answer (score 2):

there are probably a few options to deal with this:

1. just use setters, it's perfectly acceptable, but can get a bit "wordy" with a lot of config options.
2. use a config object to pass in:

   ```
   $config = (object) array(
      'prop1' => 'somevalue',
      'prop2' => 'somevalue2',
      'prop3' => 'somevalue3',
   );

   $db = new DB($config);
   ```
3. if you want to use constants, you could restrict them to the class to avoid global namespace pollution:

   ```
   class DB {
       const USER = 'mysqluser';
   }

   echo DB::USER; // for example
   ```

Comment: God, PHP makes my teeth itch. Having to do that to create an anonymous object "concisely" is ridiculous.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will definitely keep this in mind with future development :)

Comment: These days you can put them in a namespace instead of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I've had good success at doing this in two ways:

1. as @Owen recommends, using class constants

   ```
   class Config {
       const PASSWORD_LENGTH = 12;
       const SEND_PASSWORD_EMAILS = true;
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. For simple config variables (i.e. no arrays etc) the package [vlucas/phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv), available on composer, does a great job. A file `.env` contains all your config:

   ```
   PASSWORD_LENGTH=12
   SEND_PASSWORD_EMAILS=1
   ```

This is then made available via `getenv()` or the `$_ENV` superglobal.

```
    Dotenv::load(__DIR__);
    $passwordLength = $_ENV['PASSWORD_LENGTH']
```